# Changing the SVG output from the Compass inline data helper

Tags: css, svg, sass, compass

I'm currently using the Compass inline data helper to embed SVG into my stylesheets. I would like to be able to change to the output from the base64 output to something more flexible.

I'd like to be able to target the `fill` so I can change to color of the generated image using variables.

Here's an example of what is currently generated:

```
.test-svg {
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,.... etc....);
}
```

I'd like the output to be something like:

```
.test-svg {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"><rect fill="#00B1FF" width="100" height="100"/></svg>');
}
```

Outputting it like this would allow me to do something like the following:

```
$new-color: #ff0000;

@mixin change-svg-color($color) {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"><rect fill="#{$color}" width="100" height="100"/></svg>');
}

.new-svg {
    @include change-svg-color($color);
}
```

Having looked around I found something to add to my config.rb file that almost gets me what I want. https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1460 which suggests adding the following to your config.rb file:

```
require 'sass'
require 'cgi'

module Sass::Script::Functions

  def inline_svg_image(path)
    real_path = File.join(Compass.configuration.images_path, path.value)
    svg = data(real_path)
    encoded_svg = CGI::escape(svg).gsub('+', '%20')
    data_url = "url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," + encoded_svg + "')"
    Sass::Script::String.new(data_url)
  end

private

  def data(real_path)
    if File.readable?(real_path)
      File.open(real_path, "rb") {|io| io.read}
    else
      raise Compass::Error, "File not found or cannot be read: #{real_path}"
    end
  end

end
```

But this doesn't seem to give me quite what I want:

```
.test-svg {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22100%22%3E%3Crect%20fill%3D%22%2300B1FF%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22100%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
}
```

Are there any additions I can make to my config file to output it how I'd like it?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The output it gives is what?

Comment: FWIW # in a URL is reserved as the start of a fragment identifier so you'd need to URL encode that to get your data URL to work properly.

Comment: @cimmanon Output added.

Comment: You do realize that your desired output only works in Chrome, right?  I double checked in Firefox, Opera (Presto), and IE11.  The output you are getting *does* work.  http://sassmeister.com/gist/fdc69840958b4932552b